# replace specific line in file with ansible

Tags: ansible

I know how to replace strings in the file with the ansible replace module.  What I am looking at is replacing a specific line.

I have a file that has the same string in several places and I only want to replace one instance of it.

Is there a way to just replace the X instance or give it a specific line to replace?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Provide a sample of the file.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just replace the X instance or give it a specific
>   line to replace?

If it were me, I'd use the `shell` module and a standard `sed` invocation to change at a specific line. In the example below, I am using `sed` to change only the fourth line.

```
---
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
    - name: "Run sed via ansible"
      shell: sed -i '4s/bike/car/' /home/maulinglawns/slask/sed_example
```

Example of file before ansible playbook:

```
cat sed_example 
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
```

Running playbook:

```
ansible-playbook sed_with_ansible.yml -i "localhost," -k
SSH password: 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Run sed via ansible] *****************************************************
changed: [localhost]
 [WARNING]: Consider using template or lineinfile module rather than running
sed


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

File after playbook:

```
cat sed_example 
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
car plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
bike plane
```

You *might* be able to achieve this with the `lineinfile` module, but I do not know of any such switches, and could not find any in the documentation.

Comment: The sed command seems to work great.